# Graph Theory k-connectivity, G Is K-connected graph also L-connected graph where 1 <= L <= K

Tags: graph-theory

I am having trouble understanding a statement from my professor that
G is K-connected graph then G is also L-connected graph where 1 <= L <= K

The part that I do not get is that she gave an analogy that if you are a billionaire than you are millionaire as well.

I was like what? If there was such L that has L-sized vertex cut than G would not be able to be K-connected to begin with so....

Care to explain,  Geniuses ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's just check the definition:

*In graph theory, a connected graph G is said to be k-vertex-connected (or k-connected) if it has more than k vertices and remains connected whenever fewer than k vertices are removed.*

Suppose a graph is $K$-connected and $1\le L\le K$.

By definition it has more than $K$ vertices. Then certainly it has more than $L$ vertices.

By definition it remains connected whenever fewer than $K$ vertices are removed. Then certainly whenever fewer than $L$ vertices are removed, the graph remains connected.

Hence, by definition, the graph is $L$ connected as well.